# How do I structure this decision Tree?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tree

I've slowly started to learn AI programming using C#/Unity. I just finished my first FSM and want to move to decison trees now. I want it to be faily simple. Im just playing around to understand the concept before trying to advance it in any way.

I bought an AI-Unity Book with an outline of a code example in it. I dont feel like I have enough information from the book to continue with it.

This is thats in it:

A parent class **DecisionTreeNode**, from which Ill derive the other ones.

```
public class DecisionTreeNode : MonoBehaviour
{
   public virtual DecisionTreeNode MakeDecision()
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

A pseudo-abstract class **Decision**

```
public class Decision : DecisionTreeNode
{
   public Action nodeTrue;
   public Action nodeFalse;
   public virtual Action GetBranch()
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

A Pseudo-abstract class **Action**

```
public class Action : DecisionTreeNode
{
   public bool activated = false;
   public override DecisionTreeNode MakeDecision()
   {
      return this;
   }
}

public virtual void LateUpdate()
{
   if (!activated)
   return;
   // Implement your behaviors here
}
```

A final class **DecisionTree**

```
public class DecisionTree : DecisionTreeNode
{
   public DecisionTreeNode root;
   private Action actionNew;
   private Action actionOld;
}

public override DecisionTreeNode MakeDecision()
{
   return root.MakeDecision();
}

void Update()
{
   actionNew.activated = false;
   actionOld = actionNew;
   actionNew = root.MakeDecision() as Action;
   if (actionNew == null)
     actionNew = actionOld;
   actionNew.activated = true;
}
```

So lets say I want a simple game with an NPC with 4 parameters: Hungry, Thirsty, Sleepy and Bored.
These parameters can be answered by True or false (yes or no).

If it checks out to be hungry, the npc will walk to an Apple and eat it. If its instead are Sleepy, it will walk to the bed, the water if its thirsty or the ball if its bored.

How Should the Decisions be implemented?

What I understand, the decisions could be implemented as seperate classes, all derieved from DecisionTreeNode.
Like this:

```
public class FoodClass : DecisionTreeNode {} 

public void GotoApple()
{
 // Walk to the apple
}
```

Now From here I cant see how to continue.

In the Action-class's LateUpdate() It sais //Implement your behaviours here.
Should I in this function implement if/else-statements, which checks some booleans like

```
If(isHungry)
{
  foodclass.GoToApple();
}
else if(IsSleepy)
```

... and so on with all the different booleans? It seams kinda like it defeats the purpose of a DT with all these if/else-statements?

or should these node-classes all have a LateUpdate() where the classes themself here checks if the NPC is Hungry or not?

And what do you see as the purple of the class **Action** respective to **Decision**?

I really hope some of you can see how they mean to connect all of these classes with their functions to eachother. Thank you for even reading this far!